# Standard button overrides not working in lightning after Spring'18 release

Tags: lightning-experience, button-overrides, spring18

I have overridden standard 'Add Products' button of OpportunityLineItem object with a VF page. It was working fine in classic and Lightning both before Spring'18 release. But after Spring'18 release it is working only on classic. In lightning it is redirecting to the standard detail page of opportunity. Is this any issue with Spring'18 release or am I missing some settings for button override.

Comment: We are actually having exactly the same problem on our org when transferring to Lightning and it seems from the screenshot below that you using the same unmanaged code to do this.    I found this issue (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000esnHQAQ)  that is from a year ago, my theory is that the bug is resurfacing again in Winter '18

Comment: See this question from yesterday: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204163/override-new-product-on-opportunity-doesnt-work-in-lightning-experience

Answer (score 0):

As, I have observed that on Opportunity product object under **Button and Links** there exists two buttons for Add Product as per below screenshot
[image]

1st button with Name **AddProduct** is configured on Salesforce classic.
and the other button with Name **MultiAdd** is configured on Lightning experience.

So as per my understanding, you need to override the VF page on second button as well. Please verify and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

After Spring' 18 you need to assign separate standard action overrides for Different Experiences.

The action override screen for standard actions, like New, View, and Edit, has gotten a makeover. Now you can easily assign different overrides for Salesforce Classic, Lightning Experience, and mobile. For example, for the same standard action, you can set a Visualforce page override in Salesforce Classic, a Lightning page override in Lightning Experience, and a Lightning component override in mobile. This change applies to Lightning Experience, Salesforce Classic, and all versions of the Salesforce app.

Ref : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_action_overrides.htm

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply to overriding the `OpportunityLineItem` `MutiAdd` button as the only options to use are Custom S-Control or Visualforce page.